# Azure Text Moderator not found

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

API Name:

> TextModerator

have Azure Subscription and I created the cognitive service, and from a c# console, I'm trying to test the TextModerator project.

When this line is called:

```
var screenResult =
                        client.TextModeration.ScreenText("text/plain", new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)), "eng", true, true, null, true);
```

I got the following message:

> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator.Models.APIErrorException
>   : 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound''

the endpoint is like this:

```
https://contentmoderator-****.cognitiveservices.azure.com/contentmoderator
```

Any Idea?

Saad

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following base endpoint for your specific Region(ex:westus).
 https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com.

Install the client library:
Within the application directory, install the Content Moderator client library for .NET with the following command:

dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator --version 2.0.0

If you're using the Visual Studio IDE, the client library is available as a downloadable NuGet package.

Please follow the below document for Moderate Text.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/dotnet-sdk-quickstart#setting-up

[image]

Please follow the [API Reference](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf753a3f9b070c105bd2c1/operations/57cf753a3f9b070868a1f66f) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But Why Azure generates an endpoint?

Comment: Just to clarify to resolution: I updated the ContentModerator nuget to the last version 2.0.0  , And yes I used the base endpoint of my Region (France).

Comment: The Endpoint generated by Azure is useless, If any one knows Why, Thank you in advance